# Use link click to clear input field Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, textfield

I am trying to use a link to clear a text input field. I am hiding and showing a memo field and and if the user puts text in the field and clicks "remove memo" link I want to text field to clear on click.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(id) {
    var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
        if (state == 'block') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    oldTextAry = new Array();

    function changeText (fieldObj, newTexStr) {
    if (newTexStr == fieldObj.innerHTML) {
    fieldObj.innerHTML = oldTextAry[fieldObj.id];
    } else {
    oldTextAry[fieldObj.id] = fieldObj.innerHTML;
    fieldObj.innerHTML = newTexStr;
    }
    }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #hidden1 {display: none;}
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <a href="###" onclick="toggle('hidden1'); changeText(this,'Remove Memo');" class="memo" >Add Memo</a>
    </div>

    <div id="hidden1"><div class="memo">Memo: <input type="text" id="ctlWorkflow_ctlMemo381" size="45" maxlength="32" name="ctlWorkflow:ctlMemo381"></div>        </div>                     

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am stuck and cannot get the field to clear.

Comment: Where are you referencing the input element to reset the text? Do you know about label element and placeholder attribute? You might want to research them.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code in the click delegate. Sorry for the mistaken answer.

```
document.getElementById("ctlWorkflow_ctlMemo381").value = '';
```

Cheers

Comment: fieldObj is the div, not an input

Comment: Oooooops! My bad!! sorry, I'm gonna update the answer. wait please.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now how would I make it so that it would work for any field if I had more than one? how can I reference the id if the last part "381" changes as more are added to the page?          document.getElementById("ctlWorkflow_ctlMemo381").value = '';

Comment: Set all the name attibutes the same and use document.getElementsByName and it would return an array of all the elements with specified name. So you should use for statement to do whatever you want with them. Cheers

Comment: For what I am working on there can be multiple memos and only the one that should be cleared is the one next to the Remove memo field. The system returns the field names and ids. I do not have control of them. I am trying to clear each memo field if the user clicks Remove Memo on that row.

Comment: if my element id is different for every memo field, how would I get each id to use it to clear that memo's field?